# SharePoint and Active Directory group account syncing issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

We have an issue where our Test and QA and Production environments do not appear to be enumerating through the active directory groups list when the group is added to a SharePoint group (we are controlling SP access using AD groups).  These are not nested groups.  Have you any idea what could be causing this?  What is really confusing is that it is adding some, but not all.  For instance, we found 4 people who were missed in the initial group setup.  So this afternoon we added them into the AD group.  Of those 4 people, SharePoint can see 2 and can't see the other 2.  There is no properties that we can see that are different between the working and non working accounts.  2 accounts sit in the same OU and have the same group access, but SharePoint only resolves one of the accounts and can't see the other.  If it wasn't seeing any of them I would put it up to a refresh job that hadn't run yet or a sync between AD and SP, but that can't be the case here because SP is resolving some of the accounts.

We do have accounts sitting in different OUs being added to the AD Group, but this is affecting accounts that share the same OU as well.

I would appreciate any insight anyone would have.

One last thing I should mention, though I don't know if it is an issue or not, we are running Active Directory 2003.

Thank you

Comment: Have any profile synchronizations (incremental or full) been done after the changes? Are imports (incremental or full) scheduled? Are these Distribution lists or Security groups?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the token cache timeout, we had similar issues and the command bellow [(source)](http://sharepointhacker.com/?p=50) + IIS reset solved it:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname token-timeout -propertyvalue 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this didn't make a difference.